# Copy Contents of TXT file to bash subfolder

Tags: bash, scripts, json

I have an Input String

```
 [
    {
        "name": "administrators",
        "description": "Default group for DSS administrators",
        "sourceType": "LOCAL",
        "admin": true,
        "mayManageUDM": false,
        "mayCreateProjects": false,
        "mayCreateProjectsFromMacros": false,
        "mayCreateProjectsFromTemplates": false,
        "mayCreateProjectsFromDataikuApps": false,
        "mayWriteUnsafeCode": false,
        "mayWriteSafeCode": false,
        "mayCreateAuthenticatedConnections": false,
        "mayCreateCodeEnvs": false,
        "mayCreateClusters": false,
        "mayDevelopPlugins": false,
        "mayEditLibFolders": false,
        "mayManageCodeEnvs": false,
        "mayManageClusters": false,
        "mayViewIndexedHiveConnections": false,
        "mayCreatePublishedAPIServices": false,
        "mayWriteInRootProjectFolder": false,
        "mayCreateActiveWebContent": false,
        "canObtainAPITicketFromCookiesForGroupsRegex": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "dss-se-npr",
        "description": "ElevatedSupport",
        "ldapGroupNames": "dss-se-npr",
        "sourceType": "LDAP",
        "admin": true,
        "mayManageUDM": true,
        "mayCreateProjects": true,
        "mayCreateProjectsFromMacros": true,
        "mayCreateProjectsFromTemplates": true,
        "mayCreateProjectsFromDataikuApps": true,
        "mayWriteUnsafeCode": true,
        "mayWriteSafeCode": true,
        "mayCreateAuthenticatedConnections": true,
        "mayCreateCodeEnvs": true,
        "mayCreateClusters": false,
        "mayDevelopPlugins": true,
        "mayEditLibFolders": true,
        "mayManageCodeEnvs": true,
        "mayManageClusters": false,
        "mayViewIndexedHiveConnections": false,
        "mayCreatePublishedAPIServices": true,
        "mayWriteInRootProjectFolder": true,
        "mayCreateActiveWebContent": true,
        "canObtainAPITicketFromCookiesForGroupsRegex": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "dss-au-npr",
        "description": "Auditor",
        "ldapGroupNames": "dss-au-npr",
        "sourceType": "LDAP",
        "admin": false,
        "mayManageUDM": false,
        "mayCreateProjects": false,
        "mayCreateProjectsFromMacros": false,
        "mayCreateProjectsFromTemplates": false,
        "mayCreateProjectsFromDataikuApps": false,
        "mayWriteUnsafeCode": false,
        "mayWriteSafeCode": false,
        "mayCreateAuthenticatedConnections": false,
        "mayCreateCodeEnvs": false,
        "mayCreateClusters": false,
        "mayDevelopPlugins": false,
        "mayEditLibFolders": false,
        "mayManageCodeEnvs": false,
        "mayManageClusters": false,
        "mayViewIndexedHiveConnections": false,
        "mayCreatePublishedAPIServices": false,
        "mayWriteInRootProjectFolder": false,
        "mayCreateActiveWebContent": false,
        "canObtainAPITicketFromCookiesForGroupsRegex": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "dss-ba-npr",
        "description": "BusinessAnalyst",
        "ldapGroupNames": "dss-ba-npr",
        "sourceType": "LDAP",
        "admin": false,
        "mayManageUDM": false,
        "mayCreateProjects": false,
        "mayCreateProjectsFromMacros": false,
        "mayCreateProjectsFromTemplates": false,
        "mayCreateProjectsFromDataikuApps": false,
        "mayWriteUnsafeCode": false,
        "mayWriteSafeCode": false,
        "mayCreateAuthenticatedConnections": false,
        "mayCreateCodeEnvs": false,
        "mayCreateClusters": false,
        "mayDevelopPlugins": false,
        "mayEditLibFolders": false,
        "mayManageCodeEnvs": false,
        "mayManageClusters": false,
        "mayViewIndexedHiveConnections": false,
        "mayCreatePublishedAPIServices": false,
        "mayWriteInRootProjectFolder": false,
        "mayCreateActiveWebContent": false,
        "canObtainAPITicketFromCookiesForGroupsRegex": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "dss-ds-npr",
        "description": "DataScientist",
        "sourceType": "LDAP",
        "ldapGroupNames": "dss-ds-npr",
        "admin": false,
        "mayManageUDM": false,
        "mayCreateProjects": false,
        "mayCreateProjectsFromMacros": false,
        "mayCreateProjectsFromTemplates": false,
        "mayCreateProjectsFromDataikuApps": false,
        "mayWriteUnsafeCode": false,
        "mayWriteSafeCode": true,
        "mayCreateAuthenticatedConnections": false,
        "mayCreateCodeEnvs": false,
        "mayCreateClusters": false,
        "mayDevelopPlugins": false,
        "mayEditLibFolders": false,
        "mayManageCodeEnvs": false,
        "mayManageClusters": false,
        "mayViewIndexedHiveConnections": false,
        "mayCreatePublishedAPIServices": false,
        "mayWriteInRootProjectFolder": false,
        "mayCreateActiveWebContent": false,
        "canObtainAPITicketFromCookiesForGroupsRegex": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "dss-dsfe-npr",
        "description": "DataScientistFeatureEnhancement",
        "ldapGroupNames": "dss-dsfe-npr",
        "sourceType": "LDAP",
        "admin": false,
        "mayManageUDM": false,
        "mayCreateProjects": false,
        "mayCreateProjectsFromMacros": false,
        "mayCreateProjectsFromTemplates": false,
        "mayCreateProjectsFromDataikuApps": false,
        "mayWriteUnsafeCode": false,
        "mayWriteSafeCode": true,
        "mayCreateAuthenticatedConnections": false,
        "mayCreateCodeEnvs": false,
        "mayCreateClusters": false,
        "mayDevelopPlugins": true,
        "mayEditLibFolders": false,
        "mayManageCodeEnvs": false,
        "mayManageClusters": false,
        "mayViewIndexedHiveConnections": false,
        "mayCreatePublishedAPIServices": false,
        "mayWriteInRootProjectFolder": false,
        "mayCreateActiveWebContent": false,
        "canObtainAPITicketFromCookiesForGroupsRegex": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "dss-ls-npr",
        "description": "LeadScientist",
        "ldapGroupNames": "dss-ls-npr",
        "sourceType": "LDAP",
        "admin": false,
        "mayManageUDM": true,
        "mayCreateProjects": false,
        "mayCreateProjectsFromMacros": false,
        "mayCreateProjectsFromTemplates": false,
        "mayCreateProjectsFromDataikuApps": false,
        "mayWriteUnsafeCode": false,
        "mayWriteSafeCode": true,
        "mayCreateAuthenticatedConnections": false,
        "mayCreateCodeEnvs": false,
        "mayCreateClusters": false,
        "mayDevelopPlugins": false,
        "mayEditLibFolders": false,
        "mayManageCodeEnvs": false,
        "mayManageClusters": false,
        "mayViewIndexedHiveConnections": false,
        "mayCreatePublishedAPIServices": false,
        "mayWriteInRootProjectFolder": false,
        "mayCreateActiveWebContent": false,
        "canObtainAPITicketFromCookiesForGroupsRegex": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "dss-sp-npr",
        "description": "Support",
        "ldapGroupNames": "dss-sp-npr",
        "sourceType": "LDAP",
        "admin": false,
        "mayManageUDM": true,
        "mayCreateProjects": true,
        "mayCreateProjectsFromMacros": true,
        "mayCreateProjectsFromTemplates": true,
        "mayCreateProjectsFromDataikuApps": true,
        "mayWriteUnsafeCode": false,
        "mayWriteSafeCode": true,
        "mayCreateAuthenticatedConnections": false,
        "mayCreateCodeEnvs": true,
        "mayCreateClusters": false,
        "mayDevelopPlugins": true,
        "mayEditLibFolders": true,
        "mayManageCodeEnvs": true,
        "mayManageClusters": false,
        "mayViewIndexedHiveConnections": false,
        "mayCreatePublishedAPIServices": false,
        "mayWriteInRootProjectFolder": false,
        "mayCreateActiveWebContent": false,
        "canObtainAPITicketFromCookiesForGroupsRegex": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "dss-rm-npr",
        "description": "ReleaseManager",
        "ldapGroupNames": "dss-rm-npr",
        "sourceType": "LDAP",
        "admin": false,
        "mayManageUDM": false,
        "mayCreateProjects": false,
        "mayCreateProjectsFromMacros": false,
        "mayCreateProjectsFromTemplates": false,
        "mayCreateProjectsFromDataikuApps": false,
        "mayWriteUnsafeCode": false,
        "mayWriteSafeCode": false,
        "mayCreateAuthenticatedConnections": false,
        "mayCreateCodeEnvs": false,
        "mayCreateClusters": false,
        "mayDevelopPlugins": false,
        "mayEditLibFolders": false,
        "mayManageCodeEnvs": false,
        "mayManageClusters": false,
        "mayViewIndexedHiveConnections": false,
        "mayCreatePublishedAPIServices": false,
        "mayWriteInRootProjectFolder": false,
        "mayCreateActiveWebContent": false,
        "canObtainAPITicketFromCookiesForGroupsRegex": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "dss-te-npr",
        "description": "Tester",
        "ldapGroupNames": "dss-te-npr",
        "sourceType": "LDAP",
        "admin": false,
        "mayManageUDM": false,
        "mayCreateProjects": false,
        "mayCreateProjectsFromMacros": false,
        "mayCreateProjectsFromTemplates": false,
        "mayCreateProjectsFromDataikuApps": false,
        "mayWriteUnsafeCode": false,
        "mayWriteSafeCode": false,
        "mayCreateAuthenticatedConnections": false,
        "mayCreateCodeEnvs": false,
        "mayCreateClusters": false,
        "mayDevelopPlugins": false,
        "mayEditLibFolders": false,
        "mayManageCodeEnvs": false,
        "mayManageClusters": false,
        "mayViewIndexedHiveConnections": false,
        "mayCreatePublishedAPIServices": false,
        "mayWriteInRootProjectFolder": false,
        "mayCreateActiveWebContent": false,
        "canObtainAPITicketFromCookiesForGroupsRegex": ""
    }
]
```

I need the string to be copied to `/dss/data/groups.txt`

I do the following in Set-Groups.sh

```
echo $InputConf > /dss/data/groups.txt
```

However I do not get all contents, but only get the first character of the InputString.

How can I get the entire string copied to groups.txt?

Comment: Please include the code you are using to define `InputConf`.

Answer (score 1):

First if the `InputConf` actually holds entire string you should get it printed to the screen by:

```
echo $InputConf
```

If you are getting only first character the problem is earlier in your script.

The string variable which includes spaces needs to be enclosed in quotes. Since you are using double quotes inside the string, use single quotes to enclose entire string when assigning to `InputConf`.

Comment: Yes you are right - when I pass the variable from powershell to the shell script, the variable just has one character. If there was a way to pass the entire string with spaces and tabs, it would have been good.

Comment: @Win2Nx The variable needs to be enclosed in quotes. Since you are using double quotes inside the string, use single quotes to enclose entire string.